# Why my EC2 site can’t be reached from browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, localhost

I launched EC2 instance,set security group

[image]

I can ssh into my instance,update and install Apache aserver. Anyway I can not access it from Chrome browser.

```
This site can’t be reached
```

Nor from firefox

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 3.123.456.125.
```

netstat

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.0.255:137       0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.0.12:137        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.0.255:138       0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.0.12:138        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           3734/chrome --type= 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           3695/chrome         
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           3734/chrome --type= 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38227           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::60592                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

On which port? On host or on EC2?

```
netstat -ant | awk '$6 == "LISTEN" && $4 ~ /\.80$/' | wc -l
```

0

No webserver on port 80.
Why?

I got this when I ssh to my EC2

```
   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
  ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
3 package(s) needed for security, out of 24 available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-192 ~]$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:ae:75:dd:e9:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.24.192/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3149sec preferred_lft 3149sec
    inet6 fe80::ae:75ff:fedd:e9d8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Yes you should try `netstat -tulpn `

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: There is no webserver running on port 80.

Comment: Three lines are Chrome related. How to decipher them?

Comment: @squareborg What should I do?

Comment: What image did you use from aws?

Comment: t2.micro. I terminated instance but it was t2.micro

Comment: [root@ip-172-31-24-117 ec2-user]# netstat -tulpn | grep :80
 gave nothing

Comment: I mean the AMI image, as in Ubuntu, CentOS, Plesk, Some other image, the services that are running don't look like a stock image, you have installed some packages?  The short of it is that there is no Webserver running on port 80, thats why you cannot connect to it

Comment: I launced again Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0.20191217.0 x86_64 HVM

Comment: This site can’t be reached,again.

Comment: @squareborg What should I check at my EC2?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that by opening port 80 in security groups does not create a process in my EC2 instance listening on that port. That's why Apache is required(to listen port 80).
First step

```
sudo su
```

Then

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-157 ~]$ yum update -y
[root@ip-172-31-33-157 ec2-user]# yum install -y httpd.x86_64
[root@ip-172-31-33-157 ec2-user]# service httpd start
```

Now we can check

```
[root@ip-172-31-33-157 ec2-user]# service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since суб 2020-01-18 12:57:23 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 21386 (httpd)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─21386 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─21387 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─21388 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─21389 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─21390 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─21391 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Works perfect.